# How to increase the size of the SingleScrollChildView in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, scroll, scrollview, singlechildscrollview

I am making an app in which one of the pages is scrollable. I used a SingleChildScrollView to scroll over the page. I need to add more stuff to it and when I do, it gives an error because of the limited height.

Can anyone help me in expanding the size of SingleChildScrollView so that I can complete my app?
When I run the code, I see a blank screen on the phone emulator. I think its because I exceeded the page size and I am confused as to how to increase the SingleScrollChildView size in Flutter.

This is the whole code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:xdflutter/Component61.dart';
import './Component31.dart';
import './Component22.dart';
import './Component21.dart';
import './start.dart';
import 'package:adobe_xd/page_link.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';

class iPhoneXXS11Pro2 extends StatelessWidget {
  iPhoneXXS11Pro2({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xffffffff),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 290.0),
            child:
                // Adobe XD layer: 'right' (shape)
                Container(
              width: 315.0,
              height: 287.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/right.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -275.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 434.0,
              child: Text(
                'What you should know \nbefore you begin? ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 36,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -260.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 348.0,
              height: 108.0,
              child: Component31(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(-0.5, -376.5),
            child: SvgPicture.string(
              _svg_kr65u6,
              allowDrawingOutsideViewBox: true,
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -370.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 166.0,
              child: Text(
                'R:Right',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 15.0),
            child:
                // Adobe XD layer: 'left' (shape)
                Container(
              width: 307.0,
              height: 278.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/left.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -320.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 130.0,
              child: Text(
                'L:Left',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 50.0),
            child:
                // Adobe XD layer: 'face' (shape)
                Container(
              width: 312.0,
              height: 289.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(54.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/face.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -300.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 142.0,
              child: Text(
                'F:Face',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 90.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 314.0,
              height: 298.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/back.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -270.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 173.0,
              child: Text(
                'B: Back ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 130.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 314.0,
              height: 300.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/upper.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -230.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 192.0,
              child: Text(
                'U: Upper',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 165.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 310.0,
              height: 296.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/down.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -190.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 187.0,
              child: Text(
                'D: Down',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 145.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 329.0,
              child: Text(
                'R2: Right twice',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 160.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 312.0,
              height: 294.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/r2.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.5, 170.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 442.0,
              height: 0.0,
              child: Component22(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 185.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 408.0,
              child: Text(
                'Counter-clockwise \nrotations',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.5, 380.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 442.0,
              height: 0.0,
              child: Component22(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 200.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 500.0,
              height: 200.0,
              child: Component61(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.5, 260.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 442.0,
              height: 0.0,
              child: Component22(),
//        THIS IS IF I NEED TO ADD LINE BELOW SLICE TURNS
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 190.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 238.0,
              child: Text(
                'Slice turns ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 280.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 312.0,
              height: 303.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/m_anti.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, -80.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 226.0,
              child: Text(
                'M: Middle ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          new Expanded(
              child: (SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Transform.translate(
                      offset: Offset(0.0, 100.0),
                      child: Container(
                        width: 304.0,
                        height: 297.0,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                          image: DecorationImage(
                            image: const AssetImage('assets/images/m.png'),
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              )
              )
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(0.0, 250.0),
            child: Container(
              width: 304.0,
              height: 297.0,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50.0),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: const AssetImage('assets/images/m.png'),
                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(18.8, 3751.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 338.0,
              child: Text(
                'M\': Middle anti-\nclockwise ',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                  fontSize: 42,
                  color: const Color(0xff000000),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                ),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(-33.5, 4618.5),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 442.0,
              height: 0.0,
              child: Component22(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(35.5, 100.5),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 305.0,
              height: 0.0,
              child: Component22(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(35.5, 100.5),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 305.0,
              height: 0.0,
              child: Component22(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(51.0, 100.0),
            child: SizedBox(
              width: 273.0,
              height: 56.0,
              child: Component21(),
            ),
          ),
          Transform.translate(
            offset: Offset(91.0, 100.0),
            child: PageLink(
              links: [
                PageLinkInfo(
                  transition: LinkTransition.Fade,
                  ease: Curves.easeOut,
                  duration: 0.3,
                  pageBuilder: () => start(),
                ),
              ],
              child: SizedBox(
                width: 193.0,
                height: 43.0,
                child: Text(
                  'Begin learning! ',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Corbel',
                    fontSize: 28,
                    color: const Color(0xffffffff),
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                  ),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),);
  }
}

const String _svg_kr65u6 =
    '<svg viewBox="-33.5 113.5 442.0 121.0" ><path transform="translate(-33.5, 113.5)" d="M 442 0 L 0 0" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="butt" /><path transform="translate(-33.5, 234.5)" d="M 442 0 L 0 0" fill="none" stroke="#707070" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke-linecap="butt" /></svg>';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions? Can you post that as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by the below way.

```
Container(
  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  child: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: //Here your code will be here,
  ),
)
```

If you need another scroll view, ad a column as a child of scroll view, and then set again that code inside it for another scroll view.